# What is bash-static used for?

Tags: bash, static-linking

What is the purpose of bash-static compared to regular bash? Is it good as a rescue shell or what is it good for?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are probably referring to the `.deb` package `bash-static` which is a statically linked version of `bash`, which means that it is a stand-alone program that does not depend on anything else (especially libraries) on your disk.

I have used it on two different occasions:

- Installed on servers so that I always have a working `bash`, even in catastrophic situations when `ld.so` or `libc` are not functioning (absent, corrupt, ill-configured, ...)
- Delivered to customers along with my own shell scripts, so that I'm sure they have the proper version of `bash`, since I was using some advanced features that were introduced with bash v4.3.

Comment: The typical scenario is that `/` mounts ok, but `/usr` fails to mount for whatever reason. Therefore, BSD systems generally avoid dynamically linked executables in `/bin` and `/sbin`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Not sure this is actually a typical scenario. `/usr` is not supposed to be available in the first booting stages. According to the FHS, you don't want anything in `/bin` (especially `/bin/*sh`) to depend on anything in `/usr/lib`.

Comment: Ah, so *that's* why Linux has a `/lib` directory (not present on BSD systems) rather than `/usr/lib`...

Comment: @Kusalananda Right, in addition to, not rather than. The FHS states that "The `/lib` directory contains those shared library images needed to boot the system and run the commands in the root filesystem, ie. by binaries in `/bin` and `/sbin`. (footnote) Shared libraries that are only necessary for binaries in `/usr` (such as any X Window binaries) must not be in `/lib`."